# What are thee difference between running raw queries vs spark sql queries?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I start leaning `spark`, and I saw spark can run quires on SQL (`postgres` in my case).

I don't understand what advantages I can get for running queries from spark vs running them via regular queries ?

for example:

In python I can run the following raw postgres query:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "user",
                                  password = "pass",
                                  host = "127.0.0.1",
                                  port = "5432",
                                  database = "test_db") 

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select t1.name, t2.value from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t2.value > 100")
```

And the equivalent in spark:

```
_select_sql = "select t1.name, t2.value from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t2.value > 100"
df_select = spark.read.jdbc(url=url,table=_select_sql,properties=db_properties)
```

- So why to use spark for running sql queries on SQL DB ?
- I read that spark can handle data in distributing manner. But how I can see the improvements here ?
- In both cases (raw query and spark sql query) does the query will run on the postgres DB server ? so if it is, the performance will be the same ?

Comment: there is no advantage here - but the reason for it is just that you didn't continue on with processing the data and possible other data via Spark after you fetched the data from the Postgres database. I mean, the whole idea is that you can query different data sources from Spark and then in Spark do stuff with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you run a postgreSQL query through spark, and then you take the finished result, so:

1. It depends more on the task, sometimes it is justified, sometimes not - for example, make a join for data from hive and postgre
2. There is nothing here, you need to load the tables separately (select * from tb), and only then perform operations on them using the pyspark methods
3. In your example, all that pyspark does is read, it has different instructions, you gave all the instructions postgre, where they were executed. Will it be faster? - again, it all depends on the task and data and other factors. You can try point 2 and measure the time - if the data structure is simple, then I think it will be faster on postgre